# Adding read replica endpoint in PHP RedisClient (Predis)

Tags: php, redis, predis, amazon-elasticache

we am using Predis to connect to a Redis instance hosted on AWS (Elasticache). We are experiencing performance issues and after having tried other scaling-related solutions, we would like to experiment with adding read replicas in our cluster (with cluster mode disabled, no sharding, just read replicas). Elasticache offers this feature out of the box, but it the documentation of Predis is not very clear on how to use different write/read endpoints.

We currently initialize RedisClient in this way

```
$redisClient = new RedisClient(['host' => 'the primary endpoint']);
```

How can we add a read replica endpoint in constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of PRedis was a bit vague (or outdated). This is how we managed to make it work, in case someone is facing the same issue:

```
        $parameters = [
            ['host' => $primaryEndpoint, 'role' => 'master', 'alias' => 'master'],
            ['host' => $replicaEndpoint, 'role' => 'slave', 'alias' => 'slave'],
        ];

        $this->redis               = new RedisClient($parameters,
            ['replication' => true, 'throw_error' => true, 'async' => true]);
```

The `role` and `alias` properties are important.

According to PRedis docs, the replication option should be set as `'replication' => 'predis'` but this did not work. Using `'replication' => true` did.